# Developing new webapp Rails MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, web-applications

I keep getting incompatibility issues for activemodel. The current error is;

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    mongoid (~> 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
      activemodel (~> 4.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.0.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.0.0)
```

My current versions are;

- Rails 5.0.0
- ruby 2.2.2p95
- Mongo version: 3.2.6

On another but similar lines, I set my webapp without active record and have also uninstalled the gem but it always seems to resurface in my gemfile.

While creating my webapp -

```
rails new test-app --skip-active-record --skip-test-unit
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'

group :assets do
        # Use SCSS for stylesheets
        gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
        # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
        gem 'uglifier'
        # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
        gem 'coffee-rails'
end
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Mongo linker
gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/estolfo/mongoid.git'
# Turbolinks makes navigating web application faster.
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end
#Rspec for unit testing
gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:development, :test]
gem 'figaro'
gem "capybara", :group => :test
gem "database_cleaner", :group => :test
gem "mongoid-rspec", :group => :test
gem "email_spec", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", :group => :test, :require => false
gem "launchy", :group => :test
gem "factory_girl_rails", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "devise"
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

Once I changed my Gemfile specifically mongoid

```
gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/estolfo/mongoid.git', branch: 'MONGOID-4218-rails-5'
```

The error comes to be -

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    mongoid was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.0.0.beta3) was resolved to 5.0.0.beta3, which depends on
        activesupport (= 5.0.0.beta3)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.0.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.0.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.0.0)
```

Comment: Looks like your mongoid has to be of a later version 5.1.0 - see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-3870

Comment: I changed the gemfile but the error was different - Results given above.

Comment: You can omit specifying gem version explicitly and let bundler grab the most suitable one.  Alternatively, you need to explore the chain of dependencies to make sure there's no version conflict.

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/versions/5.0.0.beta3   Similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556239/ruby-on-rails-5-0-0-2-incompatible-and-conflict-with-gem-mongoid

Comment: There is something in your Gemfile that puzzles me: why are you using a fork of the official mongoid repository to install the gem?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate your development environment using the steps you provided in your question as well as your `Gemfile`. In my case I've managed to resolve the conflicts you mention and installing `mongoid` gem as follows.

First of all, I didn't know why you used a forked repo from the [official mongoid repository](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid). That way, I decided to use the official gem and changed the line in the `Gemfile` (although I think this solution still works in case you want to install the gem from the other repo): `gem 'mongoid'`.

After that, I executed a `bundle install` and got the following errors:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    quiet_assets (>= 1.0.2) was resolved to 1.0.2, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 3.1)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.0)

    rspec-rails was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.5, which depends on
      railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)
```

Examining the output I found out that the conflictive gem was `quiet_assets`. With this in mind I visited the [`quiet_assets` GitHub repository](https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets) and found the following in its README.md:

> ## Deprecation
>
> As of sprockets-rails version 3.1.0, used in current versions of
>   rails, this gem is deprecated.
>
> The asset pipeline now supports a quiet option which suppresses output
>   of asset requests:
>
> ```
> # config/environments/development.rb
>
> config.assets.quiet = true
> ```
>
> Relevant PR: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/355

It seems that the functionality of this gem can be now accomplished adding this little piece of configuration to your Rails environment files, so I removed the line requiring `quiet_assets` from the `Gemfile`, leaving the documents as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'

group :assets do
        # Use SCSS for stylesheets
        gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
        # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
        gem 'uglifier'
        # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
        gem 'coffee-rails'
end
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Mongo linker
gem 'mongoid'
# Turbolinks makes navigating web application faster.
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
end
#Rspec for unit testing
gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:development, :test]
gem 'figaro'
gem "capybara", :group => :test
gem "database_cleaner", :group => :test
gem "mongoid-rspec", :group => :test
gem "email_spec", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", :group => :test, :require => false
gem "launchy", :group => :test
gem "factory_girl_rails", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "devise"
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

After performing another `bundle install`, this time all dependencies were successfully installed.

I hope this can help you. In case this solution doesn't fit your needs, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Rails with `gem uninstall rails`.

You currently have Rails 5.0.0, but you need the activesupport fromm `5.0.0.beta3`.

So you should then run `gem install rails -v 5.0.0.beta3`.

Then try `rails new`.